# Кто может написать данную формулу на языке с++ y= ln(2)+sum{n=1}{infty}(((-1)^(n-1))*(x^n)/((2^n)*n)))

Tags: c++, математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется вывести значения функции для `x` от -1 до 1 с шагом 0.1

Comment: А что всё же меняется от -1 до 1? Потому как, судя по формуле, n меняется от 1 до бесконечности, а если менять n от -1 до 1, получится деление на 0.

Comment: Я бы предложил сначала исследовать на сходимость данный функциональный ряд прежде чем приступать непосредственно к написанию программы.

Comment: @vadosinferno Да что там исследовать - известнейший ряд... ]-2;2[

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(7) << fixed;
    for(double x = -1.0; x <= 1.0; x +=0.1)
        cout << setw(10) << x << ":   "
             << setw(8) << log(2.0+x) << endl;
}
```

[Все](http://ideone.com/Qu3H1z)!

P.S. С грустью вспоминаются времена, когда программированием занимались люди, знакомые хотя бы с азами математики...